# How to find the object inside array by a key using underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a sample array of objects as below, I want the one of the object in the array which has name Test.

```
**Results: [
 { Name: "Test",
   Age :21
   ChildrenObj:
 },
 { Name: "Something else",
   Age :21
   ChildreObj
 }**
```

I am using the below code to find it, and it is not returning me the correct data

```
var names= (_un.find(data.Results, function(item) {
        return item.Name= "Test"; 
    }));
```

any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: `return item.Name=="Test"` Test for equality, don't do assignment.

Comment: @will, thank you very much. Silly mistake i did. Thats why i am getting all the data assgined to it.

Comment: Even better, use === (3 equals) preferably. This also makes sure that they are the same type! 1=="1" is true, but 1 === "1" is not

Comment: Did it work out? @kobe

Comment: @anokrize, it worked.

Comment: perfect:) could you accept an answer? @kobe

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example, just for fun.

```js
var Results = [{
  Name: "Test",
  Age: 21,
  ChildrenObj: {}
}, {
  Name: "Something else",
  Age: 21,
  ChildrenObj: {}
}];

var names = (_.find(Results, function(item) {
  return item.Name == "Test";
}));

console.log(names);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{ 
   Name: "Test",
   Age :21
 },
 { Name: "Something else",
   Age :22
 }];
 
 
console.log(_.findWhere(data, {Age: 22}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return item.Name == "Test";
```

You are doing an assignment not a comparisson.

```
Results: [
 { Name: "Test",
   Age :21
   ChildrenObj:
 },
 { Name: "Something else",
   Age :21
   ChildreObj
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter

```
results = [
 { Name : "Test",
   Age : 21,
   ChildrenObj : null
 },
 { Name : "Something else",
   Age :21,
   ChildrenObj : null
 }];
var names = results.filter(x => x.Name === "Test");
console.log(names); // [ { Name: 'Test', Age: 21, ChildrenObj: null } ]
```